# media query sizing and positioning font

Tags: css, responsive-design, position

I've got some text I'd like to scale and then move up so it's over an image on a mobile.

```
<style>
    #rcontainer {
    height: 340px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}


.rtext span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 130px;
    font-family: "Georgia", serif;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 40px;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 110%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 720px) {
    .rtext {
        font-size: 50%;
        padding: 0 40px 100px 0;
    }
</style>


 <div id="rcontainer">
    <img alt="" src="/portals/0/Images/photos/rexanne_griffeth_contact_info_850.png" />
<p class="rtext">
    <span>Contact: Rexanne Griffeth<br />
    6000 Hospital Drive<br />
    Hannibal, MO  63401<br />
    (573) 629-3564<br />
    rexanne.griffeth@hrhonline.org
 </span></p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to size the font (which works with my media query but I can't seem to move the text up and over the image.

Here is my dev URL.  [current results](https://practice.hannibalregional.org/ContactUs/Test/tabid/101/Default.aspx)

Comment: I dont see `#rimage` applied to the image.

Comment: Christine it didn't make a difference so I removed the reference.  I just removed it from the code also.

Answer (score 0):

Change the bottom attribute in the media query:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 720px) {
.rtext {
    font-size: 50%;
    padding: 0 40px 100px 0;
    bottom: 220px
}
```